# How to add multiple button in a scrollView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to put multiple buttons in a scrollView but it just scrolls background view.

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Home"

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()

        let view = UIView()
        scrollView.frame =  self.view.bounds
        self.view.backgroundColor = .green
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .blue
        scrollView.addSubview(view)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height * 3)
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        attractivePlaceButtonSetup()
        eatDrinkButtonSetup()
        ShoppingButtonSetup()
        festivalEventButtonSetup()
        hotelGuestHouseButtonSetup()
        travellerEssentialButtonSetup()
        dealButtonSetup()
        seeDoButtonSetup()
    }
```

I wrote this code for button frame
        func eatDrinkButtonSetup(){

```
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 225, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 10, height: 150)
        button.setTitle("Eat & Drink", for: .normal)
        button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageName"), for: .normal)
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -120, left: -200, bottom: 0, right: 0)
          button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(targetEatDrink), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)

    }

}
```

I also try to such way but it just scroll a button.

```
scrollView.addSubview(attractivePlaceButtonSetup)
self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Comment: Why are you setting view frame y to self.view.frame.size.height ?
in line view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

Comment: @JasmeetKaur Kaur sorry I have no idea about it

Comment: What are your ButtonSetup() functions doing? Can you also show the code at least one of them?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using scrollview for add multiple buttons ?This can achieved easily using UICollectionView with Collection cell.

Comment: @iOSFreak I know that, this way I felt a little comfortable

Comment: @Azmal Tech Instead of adding buttons on scroll view add it on view which is above it means.view.addSubview(button).I prefer you change variable name.

Comment: @DonMag func eatDrinkSetup(){
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 225, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 10, height: 150)
    button.setTitle("Eat & Drink", for: .normal)
    button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageName"), for: .normal)
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -120, left: -200, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(targetEatDrink), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

Comment: @TusharSharma that is right  I want to use multiple button in it

Comment: @Azmal Tech Make multiple frames and keep on adding on view.But using frames is not good practice you should try visual layout format or NSlayoutConstarints.

Comment: @TusharSharma thank you, can you be more details please?

Comment: @Azmal Tech is your problem solved ? Details about what mate? Please ask

Comment: @TusharSharma still not

Comment: @Azmal Tech what is the issue.?

Comment: @TusharSharma actually I got no idea how to add multiple button in NSlayoutConstraints

Comment: NSlayoutConstarints is for adding constraints on button not creating buttons .

Comment: id just use a stack view

Answer (score 3):

```
    //Try this...
    //Background Scroll Creation

            var stickersScrollViewCount = 0
            func stickersScrollContents() {

                var xCoord: CGFloat = 5
                let yCoord: CGFloat = 5
                let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 45.0
                let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 45.0
                let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 5

                for i in 0..<stickersImageArray.count{
                    stickersScrollViewCount = i
                    // Button properties
                    let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
                    filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
                    filterButton.tag = stickersScrollViewCount
                    filterButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    filterButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
                    filterButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                    filterButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
                    let myimage = UIImage(named: stickersImageArray[stickersScrollViewCount])
                    filterButton.setImage(myimage, for: .normal)
                    filterButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(StickersActionTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                    filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                    filterButton.clipsToBounds = true
                    xCoord +=  buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons
                    bgScrollView.addSubview(filterButton)

                }
                bgScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: buttonWidth * CGFloat(stickersScrollViewCount+2), height: yCoord)

            }

//Call the function where ever you want viewDidLoad() or on Button Click!!

//Hope this helps!!!
```